# Create VSTO setup file with installshield, cannot write registry

Tags: outlook, installshield

I'm creating a deployment package of an Outlook 2013 add-in as this link 
[Outlook: Deploying an Outlook 2013 add-in (using InstallShield LE)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeamsgdev/archive/2013/11/21/outlook-deploying-an-outlook-2013-add-in-using-installshield-le.aspx)
But when trying to write to the registry, I write key to `SOFTWARE(32-Bit)` and `SOFTWARE(64-Bit)`. When I run install file it show message

> Error 1406. Could not write value  to key \SOFTWARE(32-Bit)\AAAA. Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.

How to solved that? I use InstallShield 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you did all the steps described in the [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article.

Comment: In  InstallShield LE it work, but in  InstallShield 2015 this message will show.